# Merge DataFrames With Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I got two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D']],
                   columns=['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['*', '*', '*', 100]], columns=['Key11', 'Key21', 'Key31', 'Value'])
```

That looks like:

- df1:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F |
| A | B | D |
| H | I | J |

- df2:

| Key11 | Key21 | Key31 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | * | 25 |
| D | E | F | 50 |
| * | * | * | 100 |

- Output expected:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | 25 |
| D | E | F | 50 |
| A | B | D | 25 |
| H | I | J | 1OO |

I want to merge the df1 with the df2 with conditions. I want you to search for the keys [A, B, C] but, if you do not find value for those values, to search for the same keys but with the values ['A' or *, 'B' or *, 'C' or *].
I have seen some examples using a query with a merge but dont really make it works. Could be something similar like:

```
query_line = "(Key1 == Key11 | Key11 == '*') & (Key2 == Key21 | Key21 == '*') & (Key3 == Key31| Key31 == '*')"
out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'],
                ,right_on=['Key11', 'Key21', 'Key31'], how='left').query(query_line)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: I have tried things like:
.query("(A == A | A== '*') | (B == B| B== '*') | (C== C| C== '*')") but not really works

Comment: can you please provide a more comprehensible example? Add some rows with full and intermediate matches. Also provide the expected output

Comment: Updated! I added some examples more.

Comment: Why don't you just left-merge `df2` on `df1` on the `Key`s and afterwards fill the gaps with the `Value` corresponding to the `***`-`Key`s?

Comment: Is not that simple, i upgraded the text and some examples for more information.